# Is there a better way to sync audience targeting for new users?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile, audience-targeting

There are times when a new user is added/restored to an AD group, although the access to the SharePoint sites are back, the audience targeting does not catch up immediately, causing the user to unable to view some of the audience targeted web parts. After some research online, it is found that a Full User Profile Synchronization is needed to have the audience caught up. (See [this article](http://blog.arjanfraaij.com/2011/05/adding-active-directory-ad-group-to.html) for example).

My question is - any better way to have the audience targeting catch up sooner when a user is newly added or restored? After all, the Full User Profile Sync is not meant to be scheduled too often and the running of it is relatively costly.

Environment: SharePoint 2013 On-Premise

Answer (score 0):

In the web part, which type of audience do you use? Global Audience, Security Group or SharePoint Group?

If you use Global Audience, you should start incremental synchronization and set schedule audience compilation in the user profile service application.

If you use Security Group or SharePoint Group, you should start incremental synchronization then add users into groups again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it is Security Group being used for the audience targeting. But sorry I'm not quite following what you meant by start incremental sync then add users? Could you elaborate?